# Hide DataTrigger if RelativeSource doesn't exist

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to add a DataTrigger to my base TextBox style so that it sets the foreground color to a different value if it is inside of a DataGridCell that is selected. Here is what my trigger looks like:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                 Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="White" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

This works great, except that when my TextBox is not in a DataGrid the Binding fails and writes an exception to the output window. How can I prevent this.

I basically want to say if Parent is a DataGridCell then apply this trigger otherwise ignore it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general just only apply the style where applicable. If you want implicit application use nested styles:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                        Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

If you have other parts which you want to apply to all TextBoxes take out those parts in a serarate style and use [`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) in the style which applies to the TextBoxes inside the DataGrid.

---

**Edit:** MultiDataTrigger seems to return right away if a condition is not met so you can avoid binding errors:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <vc:HasAncestorOfTypeConverter x:Key="HasAncestorOfTypeConverter" AncestorType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource HasAncestorOfTypeConverter}}"
                        Value="True" />
                <Condition
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                        Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

```cs
public class HasAncestorOfTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Type AncestorType { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        DependencyObject current = value as DependencyObject;
        while (true)
        {
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
            if (current == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (current.GetType() == AncestorType)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This of course causes quite som overhead so it might not be such a good solution, then again if the RelativeSource-binding fails it also had to go up the tree first.

Comment: Thanks H.B. but this is getting set inside of a file that we have in our custom skin. Since there will be multiple skins that override this I was hoping to put all the TextBox style triggers in the same file and not have them split out - do you know of any way to solve what I am specifically asking (maybe by using a MultiTrigger and writing my own DataTrigger class or something)?

Comment: @MattWest: A MultiDataTrigger might work, but only if the following condition is not evaluated if the first is negative, don't know if that is the case. (Is the problem the output message or just that the binding fails? The message could be knocked out)

Comment: The output message is the main problem - how do I knock that out?

Comment: @MattWest: You supposedly can control the detail of binding outputs via [an attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx). I haven't used this so far though.

Comment: @MattWest: Updated my answer with the MultiDataTrigger approach.